# How to scale x-axis logarithmically in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, scaling

I am trying to generate a ListPlot, where both the x- and y-axes are logarithmically scaled. I managed to get the y-axes right, but I cannot get the x-axes to be logarithmically scaled.

```
V1 = { { 3966.4 \[PlusMinus] 40.8, 
    71.6 \[PlusMinus] 0.65}, {2051.2 \[PlusMinus] 26.7, 
    31.2 \[PlusMinus] 0.3}, {1936.8 \[PlusMinus] 55.4,
    9.8 \[PlusMinus] 0.1}, {1816.3 \[PlusMinus] 103.4, 
    4.9 \[PlusMinus] 0.05}};

(*similar lists for V2-V6*)

grids[min_, max_] := 
  Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, Gray}, {i, Gray}], {i, Ceiling[min], 
    Floor[max], 200}];
    
Show[
 ListLogPlot[V1, PlotLegends -> Placed [{"U=1V"}, {After, Center}], 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"R in m\[CapitalOmega]", "P in mW"},  Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> grids, BaseStyle -> {FontSize, Thick, 12},   
  PlotLabel -> Style["P-R-Diagram", {Black, 14}], 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]], PlotRange-> All],

(*similar ListLogPlots for V2-V6*)
]
```

The current state of the plot is:
[image: current plot]

Changing the plot type from ListLogPlot to ListPlot doesn't make any difference. I also tried adding `{Log[#1], #2} & @@@` before `V1`.  This also didn't work.

Adding `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Automatic}` directly in `Show[]` also doesn't make a difference.

Adding `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Automatic}` inside `ListLogPlot[]` results in [image: this]
Above graphs is also the same result I get when I do `ListLogLogPlot[]` instead of `ListLogPlot[]`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Does `ListLogLogPlot` not do what you want?

Comment: As there are just 4 "glyphs" plotted and 3 of them are close together with respect to the horizontal axis, the spatial pattern in the horizontal direction won't change much but it does change a bit whether you use a log scale or not.  That has to do with what you're trying to plot rather than the plotting functions.  What is it that "also didn't work" ?

Comment: @JimB I added the results in the question

Comment: You need to give a complete example that works.  The text `(*similar ListLogPlots for V2-V6*)` doesn't produce the plots you show.

Comment: `Show[
 ListLogPlot[V1, PlotLegends -> Placed [{"U=1V"}, {After, Center}], 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"R in m\[CapitalOmega]", "P in mW"},  Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> grids, BaseStyle -> {FontSize, Thick, 12},   
  PlotLabel -> Style["P-R-Diagram", {Black, 14}], 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]],
 
 ListLogLogPlot[V2, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed [{"U=2V"}, {After, Center}], 
  PlotStyle -> Red, LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]],
 
 (*same for V3-V6 as for V2*)
 
 PlotRange -> All
 
 ]`

Comment: But you don't define `V2` (and the others) which are needed to create the figure you show.

Comment: they are also arrays just like V1:

`V2 = { {7793.5 \[PlusMinus] 79.5, 
    224.8 \[PlusMinus] 2.2}, {3039.6 \[PlusMinus] 35.4, 
    121.0 \[PlusMinus] 1.3}, {1816.3 \[PlusMinus] 103.4, 
    19.8 \[PlusMinus] 0.2}};

V3 = { {10284 \[PlusMinus] 104.8, 
    443.7 \[PlusMinus] 4.4}, {5885.1 \[PlusMinus] 62.6, 
    250.8 \[PlusMinus] 2.7}, {1816.3 \[PlusMinus] 103.4, 
    44.5 \[PlusMinus] 0.5}};
(*similar for V4, V5 and V6*)`

Comment: Add the ScalingFunctions option to the first plot (V1), not the second (V2). But, it is better to use the same function for both plots in the Show. Both ListLogLogPlot, or both ListLogPlot with the scaling function. Don't mix.

Answer (score 3):

`ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Automatic}` is the option to add to `ListPlot`. But the OP's data does not seem to need it. This shows the result more effectively:

```
ListPlot[Table[{Exp[x], Sin[Exp[x/3]]}, {x, -1, 8, 0.01}], 
 PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Automatic}]
```

[image]

The option also works in `ListLogPlot[]`.

Comment: I added the results I get when I do that in the question, it didn't work

Comment: @gluon I get this (V13.3.0): https://i.stack.imgur.com/YczWD.png

Comment: @gluon And this, if I add a `FrameTicks` option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQ4z.png

Answer (score 3):

Given the following data (which are the center data points of your glyphs), a `ListLogPlot` results in the following:

```
data = {{1767.76, 44.83}, {1780.9, 19.719}, {1783.93, 
    4.8036}, {1918.94, 9.684}, {1981.74, 123.281}, {1982.71, 
    78.552}, {1992.3, 180.38}, {2018.84, 30.948}, {3017.01, 
    123.281}, {3939.71, 70.357}, {5859.64, 248.53}, {7782.52, 
    222.6}, {7860.8, 418.38}, {9099.88, 656.61}, {10283.9, 
    439.86}, {10612.32, 886.75}, {12103.08, 725.78}, {12909.11, 
    1601.2}, {12909.91, 1105.34}};

ListLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{1200, 13500}, Automatic}, PlotLabel -> "P-R-Diagram", 
 FrameLabel -> {"R in m\[CapitalOmega]", "P in mW"}]
```

[image: Original plot]

That pretty much replicates what you label as "current state of the plot."

Now try a `ListLogLogPlot`:

```
ListLogLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "P-R-Diagram",
  FrameLabel -> {"R in m\[CapitalOmega]", "P in mW"}]
```

[image: Log log plot]

Are you claiming that this results in no change from the original plot?  Or, more specifically, that there is no change in the spatial pattern of the points?  There is a definite change.  Maybe a bit subtle but definitely a change.

There's only about a 7-to-1 ratio from the largest horizontal value to the smallest value so one shouldn't expect a log scale to do a whole lot.